# Count elements whilst predicate is true

Tags: json, while-loop, jq

I have a collection of JSON objects like so:

```
{"id":"da1234563","message":"brown fox jump over a red log"}
{"id":"da1234564","message":"brown fox jump over a red log"}
{"id":"da1234565","message":"brown fox jump over a red log"}
{"id":"da1234566","message":"brown fox jump over a red log"}
{"id":"da1234567","message":"red fox jump over a brown log"}
{"id":"da1234568","message":"another random string"}
{"id":"da1234569","message":"brown fox jump over a red log"}
```

I'd like to use `jq` to iterate over these objects and return the number of `brown fox`'s  jumping UNTIL a match is not found.

The following `jq` gives me every line with brown fox including the last line:

```
jq -n 'inputs|select(.message|test("brown fox"))'
```

How do I exclude the matches after a mismatch and count the number of matches so that `jq` returns only `4`?

Comment: I mean I only want to count the first complete block of matches. Any mismatch should stop the counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, it is best to avoid "slurping" the input, which as envisioned in the Q, can in this case can be done quite simply by using `input` (or `inputs`) and the -n command-line option.

Using a stream-oriented counting function and the built-in `while`:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);

count(while (inputs | .message|test("brown fox"); true) )
```

### An alternative

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);

def select_while(s; cond):
  label $out | s | if cond then . else break $out end;

count( select_while(inputs; .message|test("brown fox") ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option similar to @customcommander, but using `until` instead of `reduce`:

```
'[0,.] |                                                                                                                                                                                             
 until(
   (.[1] | .[0] | .message | test("brown fox")| not);
   [ .[0]+ 1 , (.[1] | .[1:]) ]) 
| .[0]'
```

https://jqplay.org/s/pAyfv7ZvQK

Comment: That's clearly better ;) — I'm sure you could do it with `while` too but I had struggled to shorten the input array; now I know how. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

With `--slurp`:

```
reduce .[] as $i ([0, true]; if .[1] and ($i.message | contains("brown fox")) then .[0] += 1 else .[1] = false end) | .[0]
```

I use `[0, true]` to know when to stop counting:

1. The boolean indicate that we should keep counting
2. The number is incremented whilst we keep matching "brown fox"
3. However as soon as we don't the flag is changed to false

I'm sure there's a better way but I just can't see it ;)

---

https://jqplay.org/s/Art_0y3u_g

Comment: nice one. I thought to use `until`, but not sure it's any better or worse